# Why it is possible to sample a discrete signal from a sequential signal but not a sequential signal from a discrete signal?

Tags: sampling

Why it is possible to sample a discrete signal from a sequential signal but not a sequential signal from a discrete signal?

I avoid making any assumptions not to write something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of discrete is normally called "continuous". The difference being that discrete signals are a function of an integer variable and continuous signal are a function of a real variable .

$$x_d[n], n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
x_c(t), t \in \mathbb{R} $$

Both are sequential since, in the sense of "values come in a set sequence" since the variables can are ordered, i.e. $t_1 < t_2$ or $n_1 > n_2$, etc.

The process of turning a continuous into a discrete signal is called "sampling", the reverse is called "reconstruction". Alternative terms are "Analog to Digital Conversion" and "Digital Analog Conversion".

Comment: Hmmm, are discrete signals necessarily restricted to functions of integer variables? Perhaps replace "function of an integer variable" with "function of a discrete variable" where discrete variables are only permitted to take on a finite or countably infinite number of values over a particular range of real values.

Comment: Interesting philosophical question. IMO, a discrete signal is just a list of numbers and hence it's countable and hence you can always write it as a function of an integer variable. This may or may not have 1:1 relationship with a physical quantity. Uniform sampling would be $x[n] = x(nT)$ but you can also write non-uniform sampling as $x[n] = x(t[n])$ where $t[n]$ are the (discrete) sampling times.

Comment: I agree, hence the sincere question. If it smells and acts like an integer (even if it is actually a set of real numbers but they themselves are or can be shown to be a function of an integer variable in most cases, but even that isn't a necessary requirement of a "discrete function"). There may be another non-philosophical concise mathematical statement that is more encompassing but agree in most cases we would have $x_d[n]$ or $x_d[nT]$ which are both functions of an integer variable.

Comment: $nT$ vs $t[n]$ is a worthwhile distinction, but otherwise don't see where "integer" would fail (without digging too hard). An advantage of "integer" is that it inherently distinguishes against "continuous", since no finite continuous interval is countable.